# How do I clean out all cookies?

Tags: asp-classic

I am looking for the best way to clean/clear all existing cookies when they visit the website and are not authenticated.

We don't allow client the ability to 'remember me' to stay logged in.  So when they do visit again, what is the best way to start fresh with cookies?

Is it to set all cookies to an empty string?
Is it to set the date of the cookies to yesterday?

Any example would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you use session cookies, they're self-clearing.

Comment: We don't use session cookies and I don't have time to rebuild that part of the system.  Just looking for how to clean out all cookies.

Comment: You clear them the way you set them. Just use null data.

Comment: Response.Cookies("YourCookie").Expires = Now() - 1?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Daniel K is correct, expiring the cookie is the best option, Your question says you want to clear ALL cookies, you can do this via the Response object:

```
For Each cookie in Response.Cookies
    Response.Cookies(cookie).Expires = DateAdd("d",-1,now())
Next
```

The problem with setting the cookie to "" - strictly speaking the cookie would still exist, if you want to expire them all so the browser discards them, use .expires

Answer (score 3):

asp.net c#
Works fine for me

```
string[] ck = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
foreach(string cookie in ck){
   Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
}
```